# Error while using inverse_transform returning value error

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I am new to LSTM and I am following a tutorial for stock price predictions.

I am trying to implement all but I keep receiving an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-87c8b43ab572> in <module>
     36 #Get the models predicted price values
     37 predicted_prices= model.predict(x_test)
---> 38 predicted_prices=scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_prices)
 
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    430                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    431
--> 432         X -= self.min_
    433         X /= self.scale_
    434         return X
 
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (401,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (401,6)
```

I am trying to find an explanation for this error, here is the code

```
company = "AC.TO"
start= dt.datetime(2012,1,1)
end= dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
data = web.DataReader(company, "yahoo", start,end)
data_df= data.filter(['Close'])
dataset= data.values
training_data_len= math.ceil(len(dataset)*.8)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train_data=scaled_data[0:training_data_len, :]
 
predication_days=60
x_train=[]
y_train=[]
 
for x in range (predication_days,len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[x-predication_days:x, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[x, 0])
 
    if x<= predication_days+1:
        print (x_train)
        print (y_train)
        print()
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1],1))
model= Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(units=25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1)
test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - predication_days:,:]
x_test=[]
y_test=dataset[training_data_len:, :]
 
for x in range(predication_days,len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[x-predication_days:x,0])
 
x_test=np.array(x_test)
x_test=np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],1))
predicted_prices= model.predict(x_test)
predicted_prices=scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_prices)
```

My question is more about the reason for this error to learn from it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are scaling all your dataset columns.

So, whenever you make a inverse_transform, you should include all columns you used on fit_transform.

To inverse only labels, you must create a scale, separately, to your features (X) and labels (y), then you can make a inverse_transform only in y, or X.

Also, it's a good pratice make a `scale.fit_transform` **ONLY** on train dataset, and then make the `scale.transform` on test dataset.

```
features_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
label_scaler =  MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

train_data = dataset[0:training_data_len, :]
test_data = dataset[training_data_len:, :]
x_train = features_scaler.fit_transform(train_data[my_feature_columns].to_numpy())
y_train = label_scaler.fit_transform(train_data[my_label_column].to_numpy())
x_test = features_scaler.transform(test_data[my_feature_columns].to_numpy())
y_test = label_scaler.transform(test_data[my_label_column].to_numpy())
```

Comment: What is ‘my_feature_columns’ in x_train?

Comment: this is the column list names used on X_train